# jenkins pipeline groovy how to run N tests in M machines in parallel

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to build pipeline for automation tests in jenkins pipeline.
I have N machines that is prepared and have label testingNode
I have M tests

I want to run the M tests on the nodes that is labeled by me with testingNode in parallel(that mean that any test can take any machine labelled and run in parallel in the machines)
machine is not limited to one test, it can run multi but not in parallel in one machine

I have done like that in groovy

```
for(int i=0;i<tests.size();i++) {
def tasks = [:]

tasks["run_${tests[i].name}"] = {
node("TestingLabel") {
        //run tests on machine that have testingLabel
   }
}

}
parallel tasks
```

This code works, but the problem with this code that if I have only 1 machine available it runs all the tests in that machine in parallel, How I can fix that?

Thanks